# Deep link with Intent Filter not working if app opened

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android, intentfilter, deeplink

I've implemented a simple deep link activity in my xamarin android app, in my activity I've set up an intent filter in order to get the value from that link and redirect the user to the splash screen.

It works when the app is not in background (closed), is not working when the app is already opened. If is opened is opening the app straight away to the current activity, skipping the DeepLInkActicity and the SlashActivity as well..

The expected result is to always execute the deep link activity and redirect the user to the splash.

DeepLinkActivity (just the top part)

```
namespace Test_Android
{
[Activity (Label = "DeepLinkActivity",
    Theme = "@style/Theme.Transparent",
    NoHistory = true
)]  
[IntentFilter(
    new [] {Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
    DataScheme="scheme",
    Categories=new [] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable })]
public class DeepLinkActivity : Activity
{
.....
```

Comment: Did you implement `onNewIntent` in your `Activity`?

Comment: No i haven't, i'm just getting the Intent in the onCreate.. do i have to use onNewIntent instead?

Comment: But `onCreate` is not called again when the `Activity` is open.

Comment: I've tried with the onResult and is not called as well.. I can try with the onNewIntent but I'm not confident that's gonna work.

Comment: What version of Android were you using?  I've hit a similar problem but it works in Android 4.4 and below and breaks in 5.0 and above.  Haven't found a solution yet.